# Browser traffic is blocked but pinging traffic isn't

Tags: networking, router, ping, blocking

In my school, the internet only allows us to connect to Email and to our school course pages where content, homework, etc is posted.

If I try to go to `hulu.com` in the browser, I get a blank unresolved page. So I thought they blocked traffic on the router.

Strangely though, if I type in `ping hulu.com` in the command prompt, I get

```
Pinging hulu.com [173.205.27.48] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 173.205.27.48: bytes=32 time=49ms TTL=49
Reply from 173.205.27.48: bytes=32 time=51ms TTL=49
Reply from 173.205.27.48: bytes=32 time=51ms TTL=49
Reply from 173.205.27.48: bytes=32 time=51ms TTL=49

Ping statistics for 173.205.27.48:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 49ms, Maximum = 51ms, Average = 50ms
```

So I'm not sure how they are blocking Hulu on the browser if Ping has no problem getting through to them.

Does anyone have any ideas? Please note I am doing this for **purely academic purposes**, even though the possibility of me watching the occasional TV show at recess exists.

Comment: The type of packet sent by a ping command is different then the type of packet sent/received by your browser. It is trivial to block Hulu in the way you have witnessed.  Your question isn't all that clear.

Comment: @Ramhound It's trivial? How would you recommend do it?

Comment: It is trivial for an ISP or for a experienced network engineer.  How this is done is outside of the scope of Superuser.  There are numerous way to achieve this outcome.

Comment: @Ramhound I guess everything is trivial for somebody

Comment: What makes this extra 'trivial' is that one can easily block HTTP (websites) without blocking DHCP (ping) with even the most basic of filtering mechanisms. They are completely different protocols so no state information and minimal packet inspection is needed to tell those two packets apart; you simply need to see that the packet is a TCP packet (instead of a UDP packet).

Comment: @Imray - I didn't and still don't see a question I can answer.  How exactly this is done is WAY beyond the scope of Superuser.  So I provided a response that was for the most part on topic here.

Comment: @krowe2 DHCP is not Ping. Ping uses ICMP

Comment: @DavidPostill You're absolutely right.

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand the concepts of Ports and proxies for this.

**Concept 1 - Proxies:**

When you try to connect via a browser to a website, the request is sent to a "proxy server" - which relays the request onto the website.. and then in turn, passes the webpage contents to your browser on its return.  Proxies can be administered to block websites based on name (title), categorisation (drugs, gambling, sports etc), URL (hulu.com), request type (HTTP, FTP, ICMP).. and so on.  Your server administrator could be blocking hulu.com, blocking TV streaming, blocking anything wiht "TV" in the title..  In this scenario, you may still get a ping reply because the type of requect is called ICMP Echo (ping), not HTTP/HTTPS (web browsing).  There is every possibility that browsing to http://173.205.27.48 will result in the webpage being displayed if this is the case.

---

**Concept 2 - Ports:**

Each different type of communication goes out and comes back on a different port number.  If your administrator has blocked traffic to this site on port number 80 (HTTP) and port number 443 (HTTPS), you will never be able to connect via a web browser, however - "ping" is the utilisation of a protocol - ICMP (Internet Control Message Protocol) and isn't bound to a specific port.  (21 = FTP, 25 = outbound email, you get the idea)  If this is the case, you will struggle to get out to the net to get to a site because all traffic on the required ports is blocked regardless of whether you connect via name or IP.

Hope one of these help.

Comment: Thanks, I did some reading about those concepts earlier, but I'm still not sure how they are being used in my case and if there is any way around it.  Do you have any recommendations on how to experiment which blocking technique is being used?

Comment: @Imray - We are not going to help you get around the filtering on the network.  These websites were blocked for a reason.

Comment: @Ramhound I want to learn, I'm not trying to hurt anybody.

Comment: Ping does not use port 1. ICMP (ping, trace) is a layer 3 protocol and uses IP datagrams. It doesn't use any layer 4 or above protocols. See http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc792.html

Comment: @Fazer I tried using the ip address directly but that doesn't work

Comment: @Imray - I never said you were.  Does not change the fact I cannot explain for ethical reasons, explain how to get around your inability, to watch Hulu on this network.

Comment: @Ramhound is there an unethical version of stackexchange?

Comment: @DavidPostill - good catch, thanks.. was having a dead-brain moment.

Answer (score 1):

One of the things that worked back when I was in school was forcing it to use HTTPS, for some reason that tricked the system into displaying the page (we were trying to access facebook). The other possibility is, as Fazer mentioned, to type the IP address in the URL bar. Finally, there's the ultimate method - through tor, which can be more or less complicated depending on how the sites are blocked.

Comment: I tried using the ip in the address bar but that didn't work. ooohh what's the "ultimate method"? sounds intriguing.

Comment: Tor is a network that lets you securely and anonymously browse the web. It's often used by people in countries with governments that try to censor the internet. Probably the easiest way to use it is with the tor browser bundle at https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en . If you're trying to connect from your school using your own computer, you can install it on there normally. If you're trying to connect from your school using one of your school's computers, then get do a portable installation on a USB drive, then you can plug that into the school computer and run it from there.